# How to achieve a fixed sidebar that becomes a navbar conditionally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

First off let me explain the desired behavior, and then I will provide examples of what I have tried. The UI I am trying to build contains a fixed sidebar that does not scroll(col-xs-2). The rest of the content(col-xs-10) should be able to scroll. When the browser is resized to < 480 the sidebar should jump to the top and now become a horizontal navBar. The content below should still be able to scroll but the navBar should remain fixed at the top. By changing the bootstrap classes via javascript I was able to achieve a version of this. For example:

```
        window.addEventListener('resize', function (event) {

        var width = event.target.innerWidth;
        var element = document.getElementById("navBar");
    
         if (width < 480) {
          element.classList.remove("nav-stacked");
         } else {
          element.classList.add("nav-stacked");
       }
 }
```

So at resolution > 480 the markup would look like this

```
 <div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked navbar-fixed-top col-sm-2 col-xs-3" id="navBar">
```

And at resolution < 480 the markup would dynamically change to this

```
<div class="nav nav-pills navbar-fixed-top col-sm-2 col-xs-3" id="navBar">
```

I feel as though there is a much cleaner way of doing this which doesn't involve me dynamically adding/remove bootstrap classes from the DOM.

Below is an example of my most recent attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/RobbyChaps/59k5s3ka/embedded/result/

## **Update**

Here is another attempt at solving this issue. Thanks to @ArshadMuhammed's comment, I have leveraged media queries to modify the css instead of javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/RobbyChaps/fs8j7rku/1/embedded/result/

As you can see above, this implementation actually mimics the behavior described in the question. However, I am still curious to see if there is a more efficient solution.

Comment: You should be able to achieve all of the styling css changes via media queries. So instead of adding/removing classes dynamically, you simply have properties for your navbar at the full width, and then define different properties for the same element inside one of the media queries.

Comment: Try with `@media (min-width:481px){ nav-stacked{ display:none; } }` & `@media (max-width:480px){ other-nav-class-name{ display:none; } }`